# Which similarity measure should be used when reporting accuracy of model that finds locations in text?

Tags: python, similarity

I have created a Python model that finds locations of an accident and their geolocation data from news articles. It does a fairly good job I think, but I need to state **how** accurate it is, i.e. how good it is. The question is: "**With which accuracy can we find the location of the accident in a news article?**"

For example, in one article my model finds the following locations:

```
Stationsplein, Zwolle (52.506100, 6.090250)
Oosterlaan, Zwolle (52.504960, 6.093270)
Westerlaan, Zwolle (52.507410, 6.086830)
N50, Kampen (52.504490, 5.980510)
```

In this case, the last location should not have been found because it's not a location of the accident. So the 100% correct output should have been:

```
Stationsplein, Zwolle (52.506100, 6.090250)
Oosterlaan, Zwolle (52.504960, 6.093270)
Westerlaan, Zwolle (52.507410, 6.086830)
```

I'm not sure how to measure the accuracy of this model. It's not a binary classification task, so I can't use any measures such as accuracy, precision, recall and f1. I've looked into things like Jaccard similarity but that does not seem applicable either. I could of course say that above example is 75% accurate (3/4 correct), but that seems a little bit limited. Thusfar I have not found other applicable accuracy measures. Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit: the Jaccard distance indeed is a good solution, and was used by me. So, question solved and edited for future references. Thanks!

Comment: I think Jaccard distance / intersection-over-union (IOU) may be applicable here. You have four locations in total and only three are in the intersection.

Comment: IOU is a good option in my opinion. Also did you try precision and recall?

Comment: @derFotik I don't remember, since this was a few years ago ;)